# How to count the number of negative values for each observation of a certain variable

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rollapply

I want to calculate total number of negative values for each observation, using previous 10 observations. I used the following code, but it does not work -

```
funda_addit <- funda_addit %>% 
  group_by(TICKER) %>%
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(NEG_EARN = rollapply(ni, 10, sum (ni<0), partial=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Actually I want to create the new variable "NEG_EARN", which is the number of negative values of previous 10 observations(10 years in my data) for the  variable "ni". I also use the following code, but it does not work -

```
funda_addit <- funda_addit %>% 
  group_by(TICKER) %>%
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(NEG_EARN = rollapply(ni, 10, length(which(ni<0)), partial=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: The third argument to `rollapply` must be a **function** but in both cases shown in the question the third argument is not a function.  Also you need `rollapplyr` with `r` on the end if you want the 10 previous values including the current value.  That uses a default of `align = "right"` otherwise the default is `align = "center"`  If you don't want to include the current value then use a width of `list(-seq(10))` which means use those offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use anonymous function call (or create a new function) instead of the whole column 'ni'

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
f1 <- function(x) sum(x < 0)
funda_addit %>% 
  group_by(TICKER) %>%
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(NEG_EARN = rollapplyr(ni, 10, FUN = f1, partial=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

EDIT: changed `rollapply` to `rollapplyr` (based on comments from @IceCreamToucan)

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
funda_addit <- data.frame(TICKER = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 20), 
      year = 1921:1940, ni = rnorm(60))
```

Comment: I think you probably want `rollaplyr` here instead of `rollapply`. See `x <- c(0, -1, -1, 0, 0);
cbind(x, roll = rollapply(x, 3, FUN = f1, partial=TRUE), roll = rollapplyr(x, 3, FUN = f1, partial=TRUE))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a vector `cumsum(ni < 0)` and then subtract a lagged version of that vector from it

```
funda_addit %>% 
  group_by(TICKER) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(neg_earn = {cs <- cumsum(ni < 0)
                     cs - lag(cs, 10, default = 0)})
```

This is equivalent to akrun's answer if you change `rollapply` to `rollapplyr`  (tested using akrun's example data)

```
use_cumsum <- 
  funda_addit %>% 
    group_by(TICKER) %>% 
    arrange(year) %>% 
    mutate(neg_earn = {cs <- cumsum(ni < 0)
                       cs - lag(cs, 10, default = 0)})

use_rollapply <- 
  funda_addit %>% 
    group_by(TICKER) %>% 
    arrange(year) %>% 
    mutate(neg_earn = rollapplyr(ni, 10, FUN = f1, partial=TRUE))

all(use_cumsum == use_rollapply)
# [1] TRUE
```